# Bootstrap button focus

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I styled my button everything is cool but can't change the blue color on click.

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
```

```
.btn.btn-primary:focus {
  background-color: and here color
}
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override each [pseudo-selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) for the button that you want to change.

If you want to avoid using `!important`, then you are going to need to override a couple more selectors that Bootstraps sets. I commented these out in the snippet for simplicity's sake.

```css
.btn.btn-primary {
  background-color: orange
}

.btn.btn-primary:active,
.btn.btn-primary:hover,
.btn.btn-primary:focus {
  background-color: orange !important;
}

/*
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active, 
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active, 
.show > .btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
  background-color: orange;
}
*/
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Log In</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

The hover `state` has priority over the active or focus. You can see it on the snippet as both element has a color change for active, but only on for hover.

```css
.btn:active { background-color: red }
.btn.btn-primary:hover { background-color: green }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">With hover</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">No hover</button>
```

To solve this, you need to specify the order, and be clear in your selectors.
hover selector needs to be before the active selector.

```css
.btn.btn-primary:hover { background-color: green }
.btn.btn-primary:active { background-color: red }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
.btn:active {
  background-color: red;
}
```